# ipmiutil is not able to discover server on lan connection

Tags: ipmi, ipmiutil

My goal is to get some IPMI based data from a HP Server through a local pc. I am using ipmiutil. I have installed the ipmiutil on local pc. I tried the following command to discover the server from local pc.

```
ipmiutil discover -b XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.
```

But it says 1 ping sent 0 responses.
I have also tried the following command:

```
ipmiutil.exe fru -N XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -U username -P mypassword
```

But I got the following error:

```
ipmiutil fru version 3.12
Connecting to node  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
ipmilan_open_session error, rv = -3
ipmilan receive from BMC failed
ipmi_open error = -3 receive from BMC failed
ipmiutil fru, receive from BMC failed
```

I think it may be connection problem. I have checked the lan connection, the server is connected to the lan. Even through putty i can access that particular server. So What may be the reason to not able to connect the server through ipmiutil???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be something wrong with the IPMI LAN configuration on the HP server.
My guess is that the IPMI LAN configuration was only partially complete.
So perhaps the IPMI LAN gateway IP/MAC is not set, or the LAN Access Mode is incorrect.

Another possibility is that the IPMI LAN IP address is not set to something unique.
Its IP must be different from the OS IP address, and from other systems on that LAN.

You can see all of the relevant parameters by running 'ipmiutil lan' from the HP server, and comparing the IP and Gateway with that of the HP OS (If Linux: 'ip addr', 'ip route').

Comment: Hi @Andy Thanks ... yes there was some lan configuration problem. I resolved it.